# Subprocess worked fine in Python 2, but fails with "Can't convert 'bytes' object" with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am reusing a code from python2 in python3.

```
value = subprocess.check_output("/usr/bin/python3 tc.py " + sys.argv[1], shell=True)
search = "TC specific commands"
read_file = open("input.py", "r")
write_file = open("output.py", "w")

for line in read_file:
   if search not in line:
      write_file.write(line)
   else:
      line = line + "\n" + value
      write_file.write(line)
```

My tc.py has code like
`print ('<Some_text>\n' + \ '<Some_text2>\n' + \ '<Some_text3>')`

In python2 the above program used to write following lines in output.py
`<Some_text> <Some_text2> <Some_text3>`

In python3, I got a syntax error
`TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

So, I change my above script as:
`line = line + "\n" + value -> line = line + "\n" + str(value)`

the output is  coming like
`b'<Some_text>\n<Some_text2>\n<Some_text3>`

How can I make output in python 3 same as I was getting earlier in python2?

Comment: Running Python as a subprocess of Python introduces all kinds of complications; is there a reason you don't simply (refactor `tc.py` so that you can) `import tc` and call its function(s) natively?

Comment: `str(value)` no, that gives you *the string represetnation of a bytes object*, it isn't what you want. You probably just want `value.decode()` (assuming you want utf8)

Comment: As a further aside, you really [want to avoid `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) here; `subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/python3", "tc.py", sys.argv[1]])` actually removes a bug (you would need to add shell quoting around  `sys.argv[1]` for it to work correctly when the file name you pass in contains shell metacharacters).

Answer (score 0):

Your subprocess output is coming in as 8-bit strings instead of Unicode. You just need to convert it.

```
value = value.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The assumption that the correct encoding is UTF-8 is generally reasonable, but might not actually be correct in your case.

Comment: worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a `bytes-string`-object.

```py
b'<Some_text>\n<Some_text2>\n<Some_text3>
```

To get a `string`-object, you have to decode it. If  you decode it, you have to use the correct encoding (default is `utf-8`).

Here's an interesting [post](https://blog.feabhas.com/2019/02/python-3-unicode-and-byte-strings/)